# Kann man „tut mir leid“ sagen, wenn ein Dritter den Fehler macht?

Tags: sociolinguistics, interjection

Ich würde gerne die verschiedenen Schichten verstehen, die es gibt, um sich zu entschuldigen.

Die Frage geht um die Angemessenheit des Ausdrucks *„Tut mir leid“* bei einem Fehler bzw. bei einer Qual, den bzw. die man selbst nicht verursacht hat.

> *Zum Beispiel ein Gespräch unter engen Freunden:*
>    – Ich bin in vier von sechs Klausuren durchgefallen.
>    – Ach, es tut mir leid. (← dieser Mensch ist aber nicht daran schuld! Natürlich nicht.)

Ich ahne, die echte Bedeutung von „Tut mir leid“ weicht von einem buchstäblichen „Tut mir leid“ ab. Wenn ich zu jemandem - wie im Beispiel - „Tut mir leid“ sage, bekomme ich ab und zu die folgende Antwort:  *Na, das soll dir nicht leid tun.*

Comment: I think that *es tut mir leid* is quite close to *I am sorry*, which also can be, but does not have to be, an apology.

Comment: @c.p. Die Fragen, die du hier verlinkt hast, sind beide sehr präzise und definiert gestellt. Die dort vorhandenen Unterfragen dienen der Konkretisierung der Hauptfrage. Dennoch hast auch du Recht, sie erweitern automatisch die Frage, und stellen die Möglichkeit eine sehr einzelfacettenorientierte Antwort zu geben. Auch kann man die eine oder andere Frage im Kontext der Frage an sich (Post) als rethorisch verstehen.

Comment: Kann man vielleicht über ein [edit] die Frage in eine Einzelfrage überführen, so dass auch die beiden Antworten noch passen?

Comment: Übrigens sollte es meiner Meinung nach im Titel *stärker* heißen, nicht *ausdrucksstärker*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ich beantworte mal die letzte Frage: Ja, das geht. Du kannst "tut mir leid" sagen, auch wenn du nicht schuld bist. Wird auch häufig verwendet, um zu kondolieren:

> *(Am Telefon)*
>   A: Ich möchte mit deinem Vater sprechen.
>   B: Der ist leider letzten Monat gestorben.
>   A: Oh, das tut mir leid.

Comment: die deutsche Variante wäre meiner Meinung nach "mein [herzliches] Beileid".

Comment: @Robert: Das ist sicher die formalere Variante. Aber "deutscher" ist sie mE nicht.

Comment: Tschuldigung, ich hatte deine Antwort akzeptiert. Aber wie userunknown richtig sagt, es beantwortet nicht die drei Fragen. (Woran ich schuld sei, weil man solle nicht vielfältige Fragen stellen.)

Comment: Ich hab ja auch geschrieben, dass ich zunächst mal einen Teil beantworte. Kein Problem.

Comment: @PMF jetzt ist es der einzige Teil ;)

Answer (score 2):

Ich persönlich finde "das tut mir Leid für dich" in dem Fall am besten. Es zeigt Mitgefühl, drückt das Richtige aus, ist aber nicht misszuverstehen im Gegensatz zu "tut mir Leid". Ich selbst gebe auf ein einfaches "tut mir Leid" auch ab und zu die Antwort "dafür kannst du ja nichts" wohingegen "tut mir Leid für dich" meiner Meinung nicht mit einschließt, dass derjenige sich dafür schuldig fühlen könnte.

Comment: Kuge, einfache Lösung (+1).

Answer (score 1):

It's the standard: Thank you! - No problem. OR you are welcome.

This does not mean you don't have to thank the next time.

Saying "Es soll dir nicht leidtuen." Just means the speaker formally acknowledges your acknowledgement of his expression of inconvenience.

Is "Tut mir leid!" stronger than "Entschuldigung?" That depends always on the voice tone but yes. Entschuldigung means literally I am in your debt please remove my debt. The long form of "Entschuldigung" is "Entschuldigen sie bitte." Which is pretty formal. "Tut mir leid!" Literally means you are sharing the pain. So yes it is more personal and therefore stronger.

Comment: You might want to move your answer to [this split up question part](http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/10866/ist-tut-mir-leid-starker-als-entschuldigung)