# Ist „tut mir leid“ stärker als „Entschuldigung“?

Tags: sociolinguistics

Ich würde gerne die verschiedenen Schichten verstehen, die es gibt, um sich zu entschuldigen. Die Frage wäre aber sehr breit. Deswegen frage ich nur:

- Ist „tut mir leid“ stärker als „Entschuldigung“? D. h. welcher Ausdruck ist zu wählen bei einem kleinen Fehler, welchen sollte man vermeiden?

Comment: Es gibt da keine Schichten. Es hängt wie immer stark vom Kontext ab, primär von der Betonung, begleitender Gestik und Mimik, wie beiläufig es gesagt wird.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ja, wir können sagen, dass "tut mir leid" stärker ist. Also wenn du einen kleinen Fehler gemacht hast, ist es besser, "Entschuldigung" zu sagen.

Außerdem wird "Entschuldigung" auch benutzt, um eine Frage einzuleiten:

> "Entschuldigung, können Sie mir sagen, wo die Bibliothek ist?"

In diesem Fall kannst du nicht sagen "tut mir leid".

Es wird auch benutzt, wenn jemand z.B. nicht verstanden hat:

> "Tut mir leid, ich habe nicht verstanden"

aber hier kannst du auch "Entschuldigung" sagen.

Übrigens bedeutet *Leid* wörtlich übersetzt auf Englisch "woe, pain".

Answer (score 7):

Ich denke man sollte hier zwischen den eigentlichen Aussagen unterscheiden - es spielt da keine Rolle, was "stärker" ist.

Wie schon beschrieben, kann "Entschuldigung" z.B. eingesetzt werden, um jemanden höflich zu unterbrechen (bei was auch immer) und z.B. eine Frage zu stellen.

Entschuldigung im Sinne von "I am sorry" ist eher formal und bedeutet, man ist "sorry"

"Es tut mir leid" signalisiert, dass man "sorry" ist, aber drückt auch Reue/Mitgefühl aus - man ist also betroffen" - quasi das "I'm afraid"-Sorry

Answer (score 2):

It's the standard: Thank you! - No problem. OR you are welcome.

This does not mean you don't have to thank the next time.

Saying "Es soll dir nicht leidtuen." Just means the speaker formally acknowledges your acknowledgement of his expression of inconvenience.

Is "Tut mir leid!" stronger than "Entschuldigung?" That depends always on the voice tone but yes. Entschuldigung means literally I am in your debt please remove my debt. The long form of "Entschuldigung" is "Entschuldigen sie bitte." Which is pretty formal. "Tut mir leid!" Literally means you are sharing the pain. So yes it is more personal and therefore stronger.